# Can C++ Pointers Affect Windows file?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have checked that pointer not providing any limit to address, We can easily access any memory address. My question is that, can it affect windows file?
Example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int *a;
    cout << ++a; // here I'm accessing address that could be any...

    return 0;
}
```

Or if I confused about pointers Please provide detail about pointers not link because I already searched about pointers but still confused.

Comment: Read about virtual memory.

Comment: @Mat pointers take virtual memory? Sorry you are just confusing me again..

Comment: I don't think you could have actually read the Wikipedia article on virtual memory in 2 minutes. Go actually read it.

Comment: I think this question warrants more of a discussion than a stackoverflow-style Q&A.

Comment: You are not accessing that memory, just pointing to it. I can point to Area 51 and the military does nothing to stop me. Once I try to go there, aka read or write the memory pointed to, things turn out differently. Also files live on the harddrive (mostly, ignoring cache), you point to the RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general your program will cause a segmentation fault if your pointer is out of bounds for your application, meaning it'll crash. There is a way to edit "outside" addresses, but that's done in a completely different manner.

In short: if you try to modify a pointer that does not belong to your program it'll crash.

Answer (score 1):

Windows, like most modern operating systems, creates containers for processes which constrain what the process can do.

Since Windows only runs on hardware with an MMU one of these steps is to give the process its own, private, address space (virtual memory).

This is done by setting up a mapping (virtual address 0x0001000 -> physical address 0xef01000, etc). Further, addresses that have not been mapped are considered "out of bounds". For example, trying to access address 0 (aka NULL) are illegal.

(Under linux, accessing memory not mapped/assigned to you generates a "segmentation fault" or segfault, under Windows it generates an access violation exception)

If you compile the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "Type a string and hit enter:\n";
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << "&s = " << (void*)&s << " -> " << s << "\n";
    std::cout << "Hit return:\n";
    std::string r;
    std::cin >> r;
    std::cout << "&s = " << (void*)&s << " -> " << s << "\n";
}
```

Go to Properties -> Linker -> Advanced and turn off "Randomized Base Address".

Now, Debug -> Start Without Debugging and type your first string, leave the window at "Hit return". Go back to Visual Studio and Debug -> Start Without Debugging again, enter a different string.

Both instances will have the same address for "&s" but when you hit return in both of them you'll see that they didn't overwrite each other.

This is possible because all of the memory-based accesses by the program are quietly re-mapped by the MMU to their real-location in physical memory.

Windows also uses this for things like [memory mapped files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx).

Of itself, pointer access is no threat to windows files. Of course, if you happen to have windows files memory mapped into your application and you are doing bad things with pointers, there is a chance you could write something to your memory mapped area and thus damage a windows file.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about Windows (many other systems like *nix or Android are the same, but some others like MCU-based stuff might be different):

- addresses (pointer values) you see in program (let's name them "logical addresses") are different from those addresses which appear on address bus to perform access to physical RAM (let's name them "physical addresses")

  - this mapping between logical and physical addresses is made by CPU (so it's really fast), but how to do it, is told to CPU in advance by operating system
- if your program tries to access logical address which is not mapped anywhere - you get an access violation exception at CPU level (C0000005 exception on Windows)
- it means that whatever you do within your program - it cannot affect anything beyond whatever-OS-has-allowed-your-program-to-do-in-advance; if you try it - you're out of luck (most likely, with access violation exception).

P.S. This explanation is extremely simplified (omitting details like TLBs etc. etc. etc.) - the idea was to provide minimum possible description to explain the question, not to explain the whole mechanics.